# Relationship of a Simplex to a Symplectic Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, simplex

I have another short question regarding terminology. The phonetic similarity of simplex and symplectic manifold has little or nothing to do with any mathematical relationship, correct?

I always considered a symplectic manifold to be a smooth manifold with an associated two form and a simplex to be a generalized tetrahedron. In conversation, someone asked me if any relationship existed between them, and I responded that there was none of which I was aware. I wanted to see if anyone could offer a potential connection or validate the absence of one.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read that Weil came up with the word "symplectic" mimicking the already in use word "complex" of latin origin. Instead, he used the corresponding Greek roots: συν/συμ (syn/sym) = with/together and πλέκω (roughly to braid/weave) to create *symplectic* "meaning" woven together or roughly "complex."

On a slightly ironic mathematical note, there is in some sense a relationship between convex geometry and symplectic geometry. Given a Hamiltonian torus action by $T$ on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, there is an associated moment map $\Phi:M\to \mathfrak{t}^*$. The image of $M$ under $\Phi$ turns out to be a polytope in $\mathfrak{t}^*$. This result is due to Atiyah-Guillemin-Sternberg, I believe. This was *not* the motivation for the name, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: There is also a beautiful connection between the Alexander-Fenchel inequalities for convex bodies and the Hodge inequalities for toric varieties in algebraic geometry. Unfortunately, I don't have a reference for this.

Comment: That sounds beautiful indeed. If you remember a reference, it'd be great if you left it here :-).

Comment: Thank you for your excellent insight! If I may risk oversimplification, the names "symplectic" and "simplex" had no intended relationship originally; however, they acquired connections by later mathematical results. As an unrelated question, do you have any opinions on the _Differential Geometry Volumes_ by M. Spivak and the book _Differential Topology_ by J. Milnor?

Comment: @Deane, Would the following paper corroborate your claim? https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.bc.edu/dist/a/54/files/2019/12/AlgCvxg.pdf

Comment: I haven't read Spivak, but I think Milnor's book is quite good.

Comment: @JPwin, yes, I think that has at least some aspects of what I mean.

Comment: There are even deeper connections between convex geometry and symplectic geometry. Recently (last 10 years) it was proven that the a positive solution to the Viterbo Conjecture (in Symplectic Geometry) would imply a positive solution to the famous Mahler Conjecture (in Convex Geometry). Also, there are connections between the Bang problem (in Convex Geometry) and the sub-additivity for symplectic capacities.